# PostMessage to a UWP application from Qt not working

Tags: windows, qt, winapi, uwp

I have a Qt (5.9.2) application which posts key strokes (`WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_CHAR`) to another application running on the Windows machine, e.g.:

```
PostMessageW(hWnd, WM_CHAR, ch.unicode(), 1);
```

While this works fine for Win32/.Net applications, it does not work for [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/design-and-ui-intro) applications. In the calling Qt app, `PostMessage()` returns without an error, but nothing seems to happen in the receiving application.

Can I expect UWP application to handle WinApi-style messages like `WM_CHAR`?

Comment: You can't even expect Win32 apps to respond to such messages. What problem are you trying to solve and why aren't you using UI Automation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - my Qt application scans some text, processes it, and needs to send it to the top-most Z-order active application.

Comment: SendInput is perfect for sending input to the active application.

Comment: @bavaza Not reliably it doesn't, or was that a statement of your goals?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - that is my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Just sending a message bypasses hooks, the threads queue state (QS_*) and shift states. It might work in a lot of applications but not everywhere.

Use `SendInput` or [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561918(v=vs.85).aspx) to automate other applications.

Comment: I don't know one way or another, but have you verified, that `SendInput` works with UWP applications? I believe it does, but never tried myself. And with UWP applications running in a fairly secured sandbox, it may fail just as well. Although I acknowledge, that that would render on-screen keyboards dysfunctional.

Comment: I don't use UWP apps but SendInput is pretty low-level and should work, it injects into the input queue in the kernel IIRC.